# Use a single character for use in a comparison statement - Assembly (Motorola 68k)

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I have this C++ code I'm trying to replicate in Assembly (68K):

```
int main()
{
    int i=0;
    char *string = "This is a string"
    while(string[i]!=' ')
    {
        /.../
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm stuck on the `string[i]!=0`, indexing part of assembly. I need to `CMP.B` with a letter `string[i]` with some `' '` in memory. I tried `CMP.B [STRING, D3],D5` with `STRING` being the string stored as a variable, `D3` being the current index as a number stored in a register and `D5` being the empty space I'm comparing it with in a register,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> CMP.B [STRING, D3],D5
> ```

This won't work: You need to use an address register and you cannot use a 32-bit offset when using a register.

Instead, load the address of `STRING` into an address register - for example `A4`:

`LEA.L (STRING), A4`

Then perform `CMP.B (0,D3,A4),D5`

**EDIT**

I don't know the assembler you are using. Using GNU assembler, the instruction `CMP.B (0,D3,A4),D5` is writen as `CMP.B (0,%D3,%A4),%D5`.

I just looked up the 68000 programmer's manual and it seems that the official syntax is: "`CMP.B (0,A4,D3.L),D5`" (or "`CMP.B (0,A4,D3.W),D5`" if only the low 16 Bits of `D3` shall be used).

The instruction accesses the byte at the address `A4+D3`, so if the register `A4` contains the address of `string[0]` (this means: `A4` contains the **value** of the pointer `string`!) and the register `D3` contains the value `i`, the instruction accesses the value `string[i]`.

That value will be compared to the low 8 bits of `D5`.

Comment: your `CMP.B (0,D3,A4),D5` has given me an error, is this how I would compare a letter from the string via its index to another value?

Comment: @Nathan Please see my edits.

Comment: thanks for the edits, could you also send the link and what point in the manual you you used?

Answer (score 2):

If `string` is at a PC-relative address, you can write something like this:

```
cmp.b   string(pc,d3.w),d5
```

But very often it is actually more efficient to load the address of the string into an address register and use post-increment addressing (it depends a bit on whether you finally need the address or the index of the first matching character.

```
    moveq  #' ',d5
    lea    string,a4     ; or string(pc)
loop:
    cmp.b  (a4)+,d5
    bne.s  loop
; now (a4,-1) has the address of the first space character
```